# UIMessage.framework issue

Tags: iphone, messaging

When I call the view-controller, I have the following options :

1. Cancel - To cancel the SMS sending functionality
2. Send - To send the SMS
3. Edit the message

When I try any of the above options, my view is reset, in short, the navigation bar id shifted by some pixels upwards on all the screens. In order to get that back, I have to close the application and re-launch the application again.

To avoid this, I am taking the user back to the home screen and then re-loading the Home page.

I use the below mentioned lines of code:

```
            [obj.m_tabcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
```

[obj.m_tabcontroller.view release];
  [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
  [controller.view release];

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks like you're not using presentModalViewController:
You should be doing something like this,

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"Subject Text"];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

and then when you wish to close the message view call

```
[self dismissModalViewController];
```

You'd probably do that from the delegate method `-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error`

The procedure is, I think, very similar for messages and mail.

Answer (score 0):

user510659 got this problem because there is a uiimage and two buttons addSubView in window...and there using a navigationbaralso...the navigation are appearing below the subview in window..
after dismissing the messagecomposer the navigation bar shift upwards..and hides the uiimage and button which are the subviews of window..

We are using presentmodelViewcontroller for calling messagecontroller..